# Can't built a quarkus maven app using mvn clean install

Tags: java, maven, quarkus

I have a quarkus maven app that worked fine before I formated my pc but now after I set everything up as it was before the format "mvn clean install" doesn't work.

Idk if I just missed something after the format or the problem lies elsewhere but I think it's worth mentioning that I'm kinda new to programming overall so keep that in mind in case it's something trivial.

This is what I get after running the command:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  15.705 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-07-19T14:17:04+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.0.1.Final:build (default) on project piksa-quarkus-1: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]         [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.JarResultBuildStep#buildRunnerJar threw an exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
[ERROR]         at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.ensureFile(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:87)
[ERROR]         at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:101)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.fs.util.ZipUtils.newZip(ZipUtils.java:130)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.JarResultBuildStep.buildThinJar(JarResultBuildStep.java:627)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.JarResultBuildStep.buildRunnerJar(JarResultBuildStep.java:222)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:909)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

These are the things I did after the format:

- Installed JDK.
- Installed Maven.
- Set all the needed paths in enviromental variables.
- Installed VS code extensions (Extension pack for java, Maven for Java, Quarkus).

- I tried installing the same Java and Maven versions I had before the format instead of the newest ones but it didn't work.

Comment: This is very unspecific. Please share the actual (full) error. I could imagine that it is a java-version problem.

Comment: @Turing85 Added the rest of the error, hope this is more useful.

Comment: Try executing with `mvn -X install` and see if there is any more useful information

Comment: @geoand This is what I get: https://imgur.com/a/fmHUDOX

Comment: That doesn't look like the complete output